# Saving the state of Zoom Level on page refresh in OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, php, openstreetmap

I followed the tutorial on the link below for HeatMap on OSM.

```
http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/generate-heatmap-with-leafletheat-and.html
```

It works fine. But I want to change something. Suppose I zoom in to value 14 but at that point I need to change the blur value of heat map. Then through $_POST I change the value of blur and the page refreshes. I loose the zoom where I was initially. But I want to save the state.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use leaflet.hash https://github.com/mlevans/leaflet-hash and the zoom and position appear in the location.hash property